# ruby on rails: multiple conditions in select array with hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, hash

This line works:

```
f = a.select{ |g|  g['done']== 'false' }.select{ |g| g['subject'].include? "send" }.pluck('id','done','subject')
```

But this line

```
f = a.select{ |g|  g['done']== 'false' && g['subject'].include? 'send' }
```

Does not. I get a

```
syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting `end'
... g['subject'].include? 'send' }
...   

                       ^
```

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: how about `include?('send')`

Comment: same error, did not fix it

Comment: The following should work `a.filter_map{ |g| g.values_at('id','done','subject') if g['done'] == 'false' && g['subject'].include?('send') }`

Comment: `include?('send')` works for me